# Android 10+ bring to foreground

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11

How can I bring the app to foreground in  android 10 and upper?
I want to bring the app to foreground in case of incoming VOIP call that detected by push notification

Comment: What have you tried so far? Since you're specifically asking for 10+ do you have solution that works for older versions but is no longer valid? Please elaborate your question

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/MajedDH/bring_to_foreground/blob/master/android/src/main/java/rikaz/tech/bringtoforeground/BringtoforegroundPlugin.java#L46-L52)
I want to use `bring_to_foreground` package in flutter but [This plugin works on android Pie and older only](https://github.com/MajedDH/bring_to_foreground/issues/5)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: What must I do exactly? I am not familiar